# fopen failing on variable filepath

Tags: c, string, fopen, filepath

This function is passed the path of a text file(mapper_path) which contains paths to other text files on each line. I am supposed to open the mapper_path.txt file, then open and evaluate each of the paths within it (example in output).
fopen succeeds on the mapper_path file but fails on the paths which it contains.
In the failure condition, it prints the EXACT path I'm trying to open.
I'm working in C on windows and running commands on Ubuntu subsystem.

How can I properly read and store the sub-path into a variable to open it?

SOLVED with Rici's suggestion!

```
int processText(char * mapper_path, tuple * letters[])
{
    char line[LINE_SIZE];
    char txt_path[MAX_PATH];

    FILE * mapper_fp = fopen(mapper_path, "r");
    if(!mapper_fp)
    {
       printf("Failed to open mapper path: %s \n", mapper_path);
       return -1;
    }
      //!!! PROBLEM IS HERE !!!
    while(fgets(txt_path, MAX_PATH, mapper_fp))
    {
       //remove newline character from end
       txt_path[strlen(txt_path)-1] = 0;

       //open each txt file path, return -1 if it fails
       FILE* fp = fopen(txt_path, "r");
       if(!fp)
       {
          printf("Failed to open file path:%s\n", txt_path);
          return -1;
       } 
       //...more unimportant code
```

prints:
Failed to open filepath:
/mnt/c/users/adam/documents/csci_4061/projects/blackbeards/testtext.txt
This is the exact path of the file i am trying to open.

Comment: That generally happens when the file path does not exist, or you do not have permission to open the file

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the problem is related to this:

> I'm working in C on windows and running commands on Ubuntu subsystem.

Presumably, you created the `mapper.txt` file using Windows tools, so it has Windows line endings. However, I think the Ubuntu subsystem does not know about Windows line endings, and so even though you open the file in mode `'r'`, it does not translate CR-LF into a single `\n`. When you then remove the `\n` at the end of the input, you still leave the `\r`.

That `\r` won't be visible when you print out the line, since all it does is move the cursor to the beginning of the line and the next character output is a `\n`. It's usually a good idea to surround strings with other text when you print debugging messages, since that can give you a clue about this sort of problem. If you'd used:

```
printf("Failed to open file path: '%s'\n", txt_path);
```

you might have seen the error:

```
'ailed to open filepath: '/mnt/c/users/adam/documents/csci_4061/projects/blackbeards/testtext.txt
```

Here, the hint that there is a `\r` at the end of the string is the overwriting of the first character of the message with the trailing apostrophe.

---

It's not quite accurate to say that `fgets` "adds a `\n` character to the end [of the line read]." It's more accurate to say that it doesn't remove that character, if it is present. It is quite possible that there isn't a newline at the end of the line. The line may be the last line in a text file which doesn't end with a newline character, for example. Or the `fgets` might have been terminated by reaching the character limit you supplied, rather than by finding a newline character.

So you are certainly better off using the `getline` interface, which has two advantages: (a) it allocates storage for the line itself, so you don't need to guess a maximum length in advance, and (b) it tells you exactly how many characters it read, so you don't have to count them.

Using that information, you can then remove a `\n` which happens to be at the end of the line, if there is one, and then remove the preceding `\r`, if there is one:

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t n_line = 0;
for (;;) {
    ssize_t n_read = getline(&line, &n_line, mapper_fp);
    if (n_read < 0) break;  /* EOF or some kind of read error */
    if (n_read > 0 && line[n_read - 1] == '\n') 
        line[nread--] = 0;
    if (n_read > 0 && line[n_read - 1] == '\r') 
        line[nread--] = 0;
    if (nread == 0) continue;  /* blank line */
    /* Handle the line read */
 }
 if (ferr(mapper_fp))
    perror("Error reading mapper file");
 free(line);
```

Comment: I did not know about the \r being added, thank you for the detailed answer! I used the strcspn function that someone suggested and it worked!

Comment: @acom:  the `strcspn` solution will work but it scans the entire input. My solution only examines two bytes, so it's a lot more efficient. In this particular case, the extra efficiency is only a minor saving but it's good to get in the habit of using non-looping (i.e constant time) algorithms where possible.

Comment: Oh ok, i'll try implementing your solution. I'd prefer being more efficient whenever possible. Thanks for your advice, I learned a lot!